# UIWebView pagination for PDFs on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf, uiwebview

UIWebView has the following properties.

gapBetweenPages
pageCount
pageLength
paginationBreakingMode
paginationMode

Is it possible to use these properties to paginate PDFs opened with UIWebView?  I've done some testing with these properties to no success.  The pageCount, which is a get only property, is always set to zero after importing the PDF.  Is there an alternative way to set spacing between PDF pages using a UIWebView.  I would like to be able to display a single PDF page when scrolling through the PDF document in the UIWebView.

I know the alternative is creating my own PDF viewer, but I'm specifically asking if it is possible with the UIWebView.